# Reducing collection of reduce in Python

Tags: python, reduce

If I am reducing over a collection in Python, what's the most efficient way to get the rest of the collection (the unvisited items) ? It is quite often that I need to reduce over a collection, but I want my reducing function to take the unvisited items of the collection I am reducing over.

edit - to clarify, I want something like:

```
reduce(lambda to-return, item, rest: (code here), collection, initial)
```

where rest is the items not yet seen by my lambda

Comment: The built-in ``reduce()`` (/``functools.reduce()`` in 3.x) doesn't support this functionality, so you would have to implement it yourself. It's unclear in your question whether or not you are already doing it manually or not, if you are, showing some code would be sensible.

Comment: Please define "unvisited".  Do you mean the elements you haven't seen yet?

Comment: yes, when you reduce over a collection, your lambda sees each item in the collection. I would like to also see the remainder of the items

Comment: @Hendekagon -- Do you want to support non-indexable collections as well?  (`sets` for instance)? Or do you want to support generator expressions?

Comment: iterators are enough. I know I could just use a list comprehension like (item for item in collection if not in return-collection) but I figured that since the iterator already knows the items it hasn't given to the reducer, it could provide them somehow

Comment: @Hendekagon -- iterators most definitely do not know that information.  In fact, there is no guarantee that an iterator will ever terminate, so the rest of the iterator is not a well defined quantity.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? It seems very, very strange to me that you would "quite often" want or need something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can do.  It expects that the "collection" be sliceable:

```
def myreduce(func,collection,*args):
    """func takes 3 parameters.  The previous value,
       the current value, and the rest of the collection"""
    def new_func(x,y):
        try:
            return func(x[1],y[1],collection[y[0]:])
        except TypeError:
            return func(x,y[1],collection[y[0]:])
    return reduce(new_func,enumerate(collection),*args)

print myreduce(lambda x,y,rest:x+y+sum(rest),range(30))
```

Note that this is *very poorly* tested.  Please test thoroughly before you attempt to use this in any real code.  If you really want this to work for any iterable, you could put a `collection = tuple(collection)` in there at the top I suppose (assuming you have enough memory to store your entire iterable in memory at once)